# Why isn't my Perl regex matching simple hostnames?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy

I failed extracting a hostname which might be both a FQDN and simple hostname

For example with sed it works fine:

```
echo test_serv1.TEST-Site-1.test.com|sed 's/\..*//'
test_serv1
echo test_serv1|sed 's/\..*//'
test_serv1
```

But in Perl I get only when its FQDN:

```
my $t='test_serv1.TEST-Site-1.test.com';
my ($res) = $t=~ /^(.*?)\./;
print "$res\n";
```

I tried different combinations for test_serv1, but it does not work, why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the same method for perl?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $t='test_serv1.TEST-Site-1.test.com';
$t =~ s/\..*//;
print "$t\n";
$t='test_serv1';
$t =~ s/\..*//;
print "$t\n";
```

Comment: Oops. Sometimes things much simpler than you think they are...10x

Answer (score 5):

The reason why `/^(.*?)\./` does not match is because there is no `.` in the simple hostname, so the match never occurs.

The following will work with both:

- **`my ($res) = $t =~ /([^.])+/;`**

  Extracts the first occurrence of continous non-`.` characters

Comment: I get "1" in $res instead of string. I replaced it to my ($res) = $t =~ /(\w+)/; and now it works fine. 10x